# malformed address error when attempting to set static IP

Tags: networking, server

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu Servier 22.04.  I'm attempting to set up a static IP address using [this guide](https://havetheknowhow.com/configure-the-server/static-ip-address/).  I below is my /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml file

```
    #This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      addresses: [192.168.1.269/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [127.0.0.53]
  version: 2
```

When I run `sudo netplan apply` I get the following error:

```
/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml:5:18: Error in network definition: malformed address '192.168.1.269/24', must be x.x.x.x/NN or x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x/NN
     addresses: [192.168.1.269/24]
```

Looking at another ask ubuntu thread, the error was there was  leading zero.  That's not the case here.  I also know that indentation is important with yaml files and I can confirm that there are six spaces before addresses, gateway4 and nameservers lines.  I'm at a loss as to why this isn't working.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP addresses are four bytes.  The dotted quad notation lists the bytes individually.  (There are other ip address formats that express four bytes that are valid.)

A byte can store a value from 0 to 255.   The last number of your ip address is 269 which is not in range for a valid value.

The highest valid value for the last byte in a host ip address with a /24 network address length would be 254.